# How do I extract specific values from SELECTED/HIGHLIGHTED rows on a GridVIew in ASP .NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView with data. The first column on this GridView is the "SELECT" column.

If the user clicks on SELECT, it highlights the entire row.

I have an event on this click action:

```
protected void gvShows_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

Basically what I want to do is for each SELECTED row, I want to extract the values for the columns:

- dataSource
- showId
- episodeId

**Here's where I'm having problems:

```
string dataSource = "";
int showId = 0;
int episodeId = 0;

foreach (DataRow row in gvShows.Rows)
if (the row is selected/highlighted then...)
{
    dataSource = the value under column "dataSrouce" for this ROW.
    showId = the value under column "showId" for this ROW.
    episodeId = the value under column "episodeId" for this ROW.
}
```

Can anyone give me a hand with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you will want to use SelectedIndexChanging (and not SelectedIndexChanged) because that will give you access to the new selected row index.  If the first cell is the button, the next three should give you the values you need:

```
    protected void gvShows_SelectedIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewSelectEventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow r = gvShows.Rows[e.NewSelectedIndex];

        string dataSource = r.Cells[1].Text;
        int showId = Convert.ToInt32(r.Cells[2].Text);
        int episodeId = Convert.ToInt32(r.Cells[3].Text);
    }
```

**Edit:**

I wanted to add that you can use the SelectedIndexChanged if you didn't want to use SelectedIndexChanging:

```
    protected void gvShows_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow r = gvShows.Rows[gvShows.SelectedIndex];

        string dataSource = r.Cells[1].Text;
        int showId = Convert.ToInt32(r.Cells[2].Text);
        int episodeId = Convert.ToInt32(r.Cells[3].Text);
    }
```

And if you are working with a database, you can add a datakey to the gridview, allowing you to pull the primary key for the record you want to work on.

Add the following to your gridview:

```
DataKeyNames="showId"
```

And then you can access this value from the codebehind:

```
int showId = Convert.ToInt32(gvShows.DataKeys[gvShows.SelectedIndex].Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to rely on the "selected/highlighted" rows' attributes. Find any attribute that could determine if it is a selected row.

Answer (score 0):

EventArgs e should have a Row property that represents the selected row.  Within there, you have access to each of the columns (called Cells).  You get into each particular cell using indexing.  So, if ShowId is in column 3, here's how you'd access it:

`e.Row.Cells[2];` (remember, it's 0-based indexing in C#).

First to get ShowId, try `e.Row.Cells[2].Text;`  That might get you what you need.

If that doesn't work, try this:

Now, within Cells[2], you have access to Controls, which again is a list of controls in that cell.  Run your code, and put a breakpoint inside of SelectedIndexChanged.  Then in your immediate window, type the code above, and hover your mouse over Cells[2] to open up the items in there.  Hover again on Controls, and look at what's in there.

Usually there's a LiteralControl, then your control with ShowId, then another LiteralControl.

Validate that, and then you'll be able to access it like `e.Row.Cells[2].Controls[1].Text` or something like that.

Comment: im not understanding this. if I do e. only a handful of items show up. I can't do e.Row...

Comment: Ok, I was wrong, Row's in the other GridView Events like delete, etc.  Instead use gridview.SelectedRow.  Sorry about that confusion.